# How to add a header field to the request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

In our environment SiteMinder is used, which adds a specific header field.
For debugging purposes, I would like to add this header field to every request.
How can I accomplish this (using ASP.NET MVC2)?

Thanks in advance!
Fria

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Were you looking for something like this?: http://blog.gregbrant.com/post/Adding-Custom-HTTP-Headers-to-an-ASPNET-MVC-Response.aspx</strike>

*Note:The above link is no longer valid*

EDIT:

You can use Fiddler to modify requests and responses.
Check this out: http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp

Comment: This doesn't work. The Response is altered there, but I need to change the Request.

Comment: Checkout the fiddler link I have added. Its a popular free tool.

Comment: link in answer is broken. Try http://blog.gregbrant.com/post/Adding-Custom-HTTP-Headers-to-an-ASPNET-MVC-Response instead

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a specific header, try using this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader(name, value);
```